# Comparing Dates in different Datatypes in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, date

Facing a weird issue.I have stored a expiry date in my database as **Varchar**(Due to a calender plugin).I have to now check for the expired items in the table.
So I wrote this SQL,first to convert the varchar(string) to date format and then compare with the current time.

```
  SELECT date_format(str_to_date(discountEndDT,'%m/%d/%Y'), '%m/%d/%Y') as dateSale
  FROM tbl_salestemplate where date_format(str_to_date(discountEndDT,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%m/%d/%Y')>DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m/%d/%Y')
```

Now this gives me result but only for the expiry dates those are till year 2013.The dates i have with expiry in 2014 are not returned even though they are greater than todays date.

Not sure what am I doing wrong.If I run a standalone query to get all the expiry dates I get all the dates including those with 2014 expiry year in the expected `m/d/y` format.
The standalone query is:

```
 SELECT *FROM tbl_salestemplate Wheredate_format(str_to_date(discountEndDT,'%m/%d/%Y'), '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Where am I actually going wrong?Can some one correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Try CURDATE() instead of now or DATE(NOW())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT date_format(str_to_date(discountEndDT,'%m/%d/%Y'), '%m/%d/%Y') as dateSale
FROM tbl_salestemplate 
where str_to_date(discountEndDT,'%m/%d/%Y')>NOW()
;
```

or even this:

```
SELECT discountEndDT as dateSale
FROM tbl_salestemplate 
where str_to_date(discountEndDT,'%m/%d/%Y')>NOW()
;
```

because the conversion `date_format(str_to_date(discountEndDT,'%m/%d/%Y'), '%m/%d/%Y')` in fact converts a string m/d/yyyy to date, then back to the same string m/d/yyyy.
See this demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59536/5

Your query is not comparing true dates, but is comparing strings in the format: m/d/yyyy, where `m` is a month number.
Take a look at the result of the second query in the demo.
For example a date "03/15/2014" is greather than "12/09/2013", but a string "03..." is less than "12...", therefore you get unexpected results.

Comment: Yes I knew that was the issue but messed up with the formats!